# Probability of one event happening first given the second event?

Tags: probability

> A bag contains 5 red balls and 6 green balls. If two balls are taken
>   out successively, without replacement, what is the probability that
>   green is picked on the first pick given that at least one red is
>   chosen?

I know the answer is 3/8, however I have no idea how to get there.

I've tried taking it as 6/11 first pick red, 5/10 second green, wrong, along with several other variations in that vein, but it generally boils down to the fact that I don't understand what to do with "at least one green is chosen."
Am I supposed to take that as 5/10 chance knowing the green is second? Treating the second event as 100% chance of being green doesn't work either?

Comment: You need to first work with the definition of $P[A|B]$ for the events $A, B$ relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If at least one red is chosen, it is either $RR, RG, GR$ (that is we just have to exclude $GG$) and you are interested in $GR$.

Hence the probability is

\begin{align}\frac{P(GR)}{1-P(GG)}&=\frac{\frac{6}{11}\cdot \frac{5}{10}}{1-\frac{6}{11}\cdot \frac{5}{10}} \\
&=\frac{\frac{3}{11}}{\frac{8}{11}}\\
&= \frac{3}{8}\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$A$ be the event that green is chosen on the first try. $B$ be the event that atleast one red is chosen $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A).P(A)}{P(B|A).P(A)+P(B|\bar{A})P(\bar{A})} \\ =\frac{(5/10)(6/11)}{(5/10)(6/11)+1.(5/11)}=\frac38$$